# Install Shoreditch Extension

Tags: wordpress, extension, shoreditch

Downloaded and installed Shoreditch Extension 0.1-- alpha12.zip on CiviCRM 4.7.27, WordPress 4.8.3, yet I cannot see any change in the theme.

Haven't found any evidence of installation errors so far. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling, no change.

There is now an option under Resource URLs - Custom CSS for Shoreditch, but when I select that option I lose all CiviCRM menus.

Does anyone know what else I have to do to make this extension go?

Ultimate goal is to get Mosaico extension installed.

Comment: edited question - CiviCRM version is 4.7.27

Comment: The theme is visible now, but there are significant issues with the layout of many standard forms/tables such as overlapping text, etc. It's going to take a lot of fudging to get it readable on every page. Kind of disappointing.

Comment: It was developed on a minimalist Drupal theme, so it's possible some elements of the WP stock theme are interfering with their design. Obviously it's never been tested on WP.

Comment: We're going to put some effort into making it work on WP properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like a bug in the shoreditch theme. It reduces the z-index of the civicrm menu, which causes it to be hidden behind the wordpress menu.

I've found a [bug report](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/issues/82) on this, and a [pull-request](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/pull/90) which fixes it. Hopefully that will make it into the next version.

Comment: Thanks brother, that's the clue I was looking for. I took the z-index reference out of the #civicrm-menu section in the custom-civicrm.css and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Shoreditch extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch) Release table, Shoreditch is compatible only with CiviCRM 4.7.

Comment: sorry obvious typo - CiviCRM version 4.7.27